# Is foreach executed at compile time?

Tags: d

I wrote this piece of code to get hold of the types of a function passed by a pointer:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.traits;

void main()
{
  get_param_types(&f1,"f1");
  get_param_types(&f2,"f2");
  get_param_types(&f3,"f3");
}

void get_param_types(f_t)(f_t f, string f_id){
  writeln("get_param_types ");
  alias ParameterTypeTuple!(f) ptt;
  writeln(f_id, " has ", ptt.length, " parameters");
  static if (ptt.length){
    write("( ");
    foreach (pt; ptt){
      write(typeid(pt), " ");
    }
    writeln(")");
  }
}

void f1() { }
void f2(int x) { }
void f3(int x, double y, string z) { }
```

My doubt is: **1: Is `get_param_types` completely evaluated at compile time?**

If not: **2: How can I achieve this?**

And while I am at it... **3: Is there a way to avoid passing the strings (e.g. `"f1"`) and deduce them from within `get_param_types` at compile time?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `get_param_types()` in your example is evaluated at runtime, as you are calling it at runtime in `main()`. Note that it cannot be evaluated at compile time as-is, as you are making calls to write() and writeln() which write to `stdout`, which isn't available at compile time.
2. What is it you want to achieve at compile time? All the calls to `write` and `writeln` can only happen at runtime in your example. The `foreach` and `static if` are evaluated at compile time... Essentially any call to that function will, at runtime, just call a combination of `write` and `writeln` - no loops or conditionals - is this what you want?
3. You may like to look into [template alias parameters](http://dlang.org/template.html#aliasparameters). They look a little like this:

```c#
void getParamTypes(alias fn)() if (isCallable!fn)
{
    writefln("Getting parameter types for fn: %s", (&fn).stringof[2..$]);
    foreach (param; ParameterTypeTuple!fn) {
        writeln(param.stringof);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `write` calls are just for debugging. So if I get rid of them (or `debug` them, I will edit the post) it will be executed at compile time, right? I was sure about `static if` just not about `foreach`. The `alias`-`stringof` combi works like charm! What is the `isCallable` for? As far as I can see it just shortens the error message when I call the function with a non callable...

Comment: foreach() will be unrolled at compile time when iterating over a tuple. That is, there will be no iteration at runtime, it will just be a list of statements. The isCallable specifies that the alias must be something that can be called (a function, delegate, struct or class with opCall()). It tends to make usage and error messages clearer.

Answer (score 3):

the foreach will be *expanded* at compile time but the code execution (like the runtime only functions like write) can be deferred to runtime

this is comparable to loop unrolling but here not with a counter but unique type each iteration